# Which Installation Process Should I Choose On The Virtual Machine?

Tags: installation, virtualization

This is what I have done so far:

- Downloaded the ISO for Ubuntu
- Downloaded and installed Oracle VM
  VirtualBox
- Set up my virtual machine in VirtualBox
- Mounted the Ubuntu ISO in my virtual machine
- Started ubuntu successfully for the first time
- Reached the setup/install for Ubuntu

Anyways, I'm at this page:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/04O9I.png

So, as you can see, I'm at the install menu and there's two options: Try Ubuntu and Install Ubuntu.

I want to fully install Ubuntu to my virtual machine. However, I only want it on my virtual machine. When I click "Install Ubuntu" it says "Erase disk and install Ubuntu Warning this will delete any files on the disk."

What disk is that message referring to? I want to install Ubuntu so its only on my virtual machine, I don't want it to mess up Windows (which is what my real machine is running) nor do I want it to mess with my files on my real machine.

So, what do I do to install Ubuntu solely to my virtual machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is referring to the disk that the virtual machine sees, the virtual disk, so selecting "Install Ubuntu" and wiping everything will stay contained within the virtual machine.

(Remember this is why VMs are so great, as far as ubuntu is concerned the whole disk is whatever you defined in Virtualbox)